# ipad ip address using command line tools

Tags: ios, command-line, ip, command-line-interface

I have an iOS device (iPhone or iPad) hooked up to my mac laptop.  Obviously, you can get the IP address of the iOS device from settings, but is there a way to do this using command line tools (without rooting the iOS device)?  I need to be able to do this for some test automation.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install open ssl
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew install arp-scan
macaddr=$(ideviceinfo -u <UUID OF DEVICE> -k WiFiAddress)
arp-scan --interface=<eth interface connected to same wifi> --localnet | grep $mac_addr"
```

This is flaky, because you need to force the devices to see each other on the LAN. I work around it turning wifi on and off on the device.
This is the best solution I have found. I generally cache this info since getting it dynamically is unreliable. arp-scan also requires you be root to access the network device.

Answer (score -4):

You can use this web service to know your IP Address , the web service returns you an XML with your ip-address ...

http://www.domaintools.com/research/my-ip/myip.xml

Comment: He probably means the LAN IP.

Comment: This would require opening safari on the device itself, which means you are not using the command line.